# Split filter function?

Tags: python, filter, functional-programming

Is there some function that acts as `filter` but also returns the list of rejected values? For example, I might want to do something like split a list into values greater and lower than 5. So if I have an array `a` I might say apply this hypothetical function `splitfilter` as follows:

`lower, higher = splitfilter(lambda x: x<5, a)`

Answer (score 1):

This function is not built-in, to my knowledge. If we want to eagerly consume the input iterable and produce lists as output, then this is fairly straightforward to write.

```
def splitfilter(p, xs):
  t, f = [], []
  for x in xs:
    if p(x):
      t.append(x)
    else:
      f.append(x)
  return t, f
```

On the other hand, if our *input* is a multi-pass iterable and we want lazy output, we can do something like this, keeping in mind that this will iterate the input list twice.

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def splitfilter_lazy(f, xs):
  return filter(f, xs), filterfalse(f, xs)
```

I suspect that's exactly why it's not provided. Most of the built-in `itertools` functionality (and `map` and `filter` are `itertools` in spirit; they're just important enough to be included in `builtins`) take input and produce output in the form of (lazy) iterators, and with this function there's a choice of tradeoff: Do you want eager output but only one iteration on the input, or do you want proper iterators as output but to force the input to be multi-pass?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't clarify it well in the question but I was wondering about lazy loading. I came across this when I was doing two filters and realizing it would iterate twice. It won't matter in practice, but I've been learning pure functional techniques where this would seems reasonable to have.

Comment: Yeah, if you're comparing it to Haskell (where a "lazy" version of this is straightforward), you'll be disappointed in Python, unfortunately. The `partition` function in Haskell is able to tie the input thunk to the two output thunks in a complicated way that it isn't really possible to do in Python in a straightforward way. You could probably rig up an iterator class yourself that has that behavior, but it would be a lot of work and you'd basically be reimplementing `iterttools.tee` at that point.